# Update Mongoose update records with ejs templating

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an web app with `node.js` and `express` with `mongoose`. I have a candidate profile that has a lot of inputs like user personal (name address etc.), info, parents info and next of kin. I view for the candidate profile.
My question is, what's the best approach to edit the user data?

Do I go the approach of rendering the whole candidate profile and making changes and updating, or I make the option to edit fields individually which will make me have a lot of code for each field, or are there better suggestions.